# Subtracting counts (DataFrame.count()) from a DataFrame entry in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a counts on `df1` that I want to subtract from an entry in `df2`.

Specifically, I want to subtract the number of customers having **zero** income from the `2018` row in `df2` :

```
count = df1[df1['income']==0].count()

df2.loc('2018', 'income') -= count
```

I get the warning:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy "

The problem seems to be that DataFrame.counts() returns a Series and not a number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `len` for length of `DataFrame`:

```
count = len(df1[df1['income']==0])
```

But better is sum `True`s in condition, `True`s are processes like `1`:

```
count = (df1['income']==0).sum()
```

Comment: Still get the warning though, but it worked. Does it cause any problems?